# Problems with Parallels and backing up with Time Machine

Tags: macos, time-machine, parallels-desktop

I use Macbook Air and Lion. I use Time Machine to back up on my Drobo FS. All seems to be ok until I use Parallels. The Time Machine seems to take my virtual machine as one file so every time I open it Time machine wants to back up the WHOLE virtual machine although I maybe have changed only a word in a file. This leads to huge back ups of 20-30 G. Is there anything I can do about this unnecessary backup? Or is there any way I can tell the Time Machine not to back up my Windows files? Can I use tmutil and in that case how?

Camilla

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parallels have instructions [here](http://kb.parallels.com/8827) for making their software (version 6 or later) work better with Time Machine. You can either optimise your VMs for Time Machine backup, or disable backup for them.

> Parallels Desktop for Mac includes improved integration with Time Machine. 
>   When backing up the virtual machine, it will only backup the recent changes (the latest snapshot), but not the whole virtual hard drive.
>   Thus, the backup process will take less time and use less space on your Time Machine storage device.
>
> To enable improved integration with Time Machine, please go to Virtual Machine Configuration, choose Options and hit Backup.
>
> Select "Optimize for Time Machine" in SmartGuard menu.
>
> If you do not want your virtual machine to be backed up by Time Machine, you need go to Virtual Machine Configuration --> Options --> Backup and put a checkmark on “Do not back up with Time Machine”.

---

In Parallels 7 the control panel looks like this:

[image]

Note that when you enable this feature, it will take up more space on the disk. Also, Auto Compress will be disabled.