# Profiling Time Machine on OS/X Mavericks

Tags: macos, time-machine

I know that it's possible to end up wasting a lot of space in Time Machine with backing up huge files that have changed only a little (like [a Parallels image that is not optimized for time machine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31960/problems-with-parallels-and-backing-up-with-time-machine)) and it seems to me possible that there are also some cases in which one gets lots of little files that are constantly changing or coming and going, like a web cache would do if Time Machine weren't already configured to refrain from backing the cache up.

[Apparently there is or was a bug in Chrome that causes such issues.](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25959)

Is there a tool out there that can detect if I'm wasting a bunch of space somewhere? To detect big files it might tell me `(Total space dedicated to versions of file X) - (space required for latest version of file X)`; there might be a more complicated analogue for directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two best tools I have discovered are `tmutil` which is bundled with OS X and [BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) which is excellent software for deeply inspecting your backups.

I would start with the graphical program BackupLoupe and try out a command like `tmutil compare` to see what Apple's tools provide to show you what will be part of the next backup interval.

Comment: While working with BackupLoupe I stumbled onto a link to a program called [Time Tracker](http://www.charlessoft.com/). The developer's site says, "TimeTracker is in an extremely early state, and is as such very unpolished," but for the sake of completeness, here it is.